# Concatenating SoundEffects (wav) and saving to isolated storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, arrays, soundeffect

I am having an awful time trying to come up with a good solution to this problem of mine.

I have 3 sound effects that are marked as content on the phone, all the same bitrate.

- sound1.wav
- sound2.wav
- sound3.wav

I want the user to be able to be able to select in any order, or however many times they like, the play order of the wav files, and then generate a new wav file based on their choices which can be stored and brought back from isolated storage.

So `Thank You Walt Ritscher` with the help so far, but as you will eventually see my coding skills are fragmented at best. What I'm trying to convey in the following code is that a user will be prompted to select any/all of the sounds with a tap event, and his selections will determine what the new soundeffect will sound like (it's order, etc) However there is still a lot I don't know about and here is the code I came up with (while not on my coding computer);

```
//SO I have this master list of sounds to use, indicated in this block of code:
//sound1.wav, sound2.wav, sound3.wav
// my wav files are marked as resources
// get the wav file from the DLL
var streamInfo1 = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri(sound1.wav, UriKind.Relative));
var streamInfo2 = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri(sound2.wav, UriKind.Relative));
var streamInfo3 = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri(sound3.wav, UriKind.Relative));

//With the above declarations made, I run each one as a stream as a variable.
var stream1 = streamInfo1.Stream as UnmanagedMemoryStream;
var stream2 = streamInfo2.Stream as UnmanagedMemoryStream;
var stream3 = streamInfo3.Stream as UnmanagedMemoryStream;



//The user can choose the sounds in any order, and repeat if desired.
//Let us assume the user chose in this order:
//sound1.wav + sound1.wav + sound2.wav +sound3.wav


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var bytesA = new byte[stream1.Length];
  var bytesB = new byte[stream1.Length];
  var bytesC = new byte[stream2.Length];
}

// read the bytes from the stream into the array
stream1.Read(bytesA, 0, (int)stream1.Length);
stream2.Read(bytesB, 0, (int)stream1.Length);
stream3.Read(bytesC, 0, (int)stream2.Length);

var combined = new byte[bytesA.Length + bytesA.Length + bytesB.Length] + bytesC.Length]];

// copy the bytes into the combined array
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesA, 0, combined, 0, bytesA.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesB, 0, combined, bytesA.Length, bytesB.Length);

var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
outputStream.Write(combined, 0, combined.Length);

// substitute your own sample rate
var effect = new SoundEffect(
      buffer: outputStream.ToArray(),
      sampleRate: 48000,
      channels: AudioChannels.Mono);
var instance = effect.CreateInstance();
instance.Play();

// save stream to IsolatedStorage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to get the bytes from the stream and combine into a new byte array.  Then store that array into an UnmanagedMemoryStream.

```
   // my wav files are marked as resources
   // get the wav file from the DLL
   var streamInfo1 = Application.GetResourceStream(
        new Uri(loopWav, UriKind.Relative));
   var streamInfo2 = Application.GetResourceStream(
        new Uri(beatWav, UriKind.Relative));

    var stream1 = streamInfo1.Stream as UnmanagedMemoryStream;
    var stream2 = streamInfo2.Stream as UnmanagedMemoryStream;

    var bytesA = new byte[stream1.Length];
    var bytesB = new byte[stream2.Length];

    // read the bytes from the stream into the array
    stream1.Read(bytesA, 0, (int)stream1.Length);
    stream2.Read(bytesB, 0, (int)stream2.Length);

    var combined = new byte[bytesA.Length + bytesB.Length];

    // copy the bytes into the combined array
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesA, 0, combined, 0, bytesA.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesB, 0, combined, bytesA.Length, bytesB.Length);

    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    outputStream.Write(combined, 0, combined.Length);

    // substitute your own sample rate
    var effect = new SoundEffect(
          buffer: outputStream.ToArray(),
          sampleRate: 48000,
          channels: AudioChannels.Mono);


    var instance = effect.CreateInstance();
    instance.Play();

    // save stream to IsolatedStorage
```

I've written more about WP7 audio for CoDe Magazine.

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=1109071

Comment: In trying to apply this to what I need (and thank you for the wonderful code sample) I should go ahead and give each sound file a unique "var bytes#" and create a corresponding unique "stream#.read" line respectively. I could create a while (i=0, i<max, i++) loop to go ahead and assign each "stream#.read" to fill in a "var combined".. such as "var combined = new byte[[i1].Length + [i2].Length....];?

Comment: I'll answer my own question just to give a better visual of the code, and take it down when the problem is solved to give you the proper credit :)

Comment: YOu can modify your own question and add the visuals there.

Comment: I tried my best to do it from memory, but as I'm not sitting in front of my home computer I cannot create the most elegant (or proper) code. I hope it conveyed what I was aiming for.